# SQLAlchemy error when inserting into a table whose Primary Key is also a Foreign Key

Tags: python, sql-server, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to interact with a SQL Server database.

One of the tables in my database has a primary key which is also a foreign key (modelling an optional one-to-one relationship). Trying to insert into this table using the SQLAlchemy ORM produces an unexpected error; SQLAlchemy appears to try to create a new row in the foreign table, whose ID is then used as the value for the foreign/primary key column - completely ignoring the explicitly-specified value for that column.

To be concrete, the relevant part of my DB schema is the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataType] (
  [Id] INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Name] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  [DataTable] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Type] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataSet] (
  [Id] INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
  [DataTypeId] INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_DataSet] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_DataSet_DataType] FOREIGN KEY ([DataTypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Type] ([Id]),
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ScalarData] (
  [DataSetId] INT NOT NULL,
  [Value] VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_ScalarData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DataSetId] ASC),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_ScalarData_DataSet] FOREIGN KEY ([DataSetId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[DataSet] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
)
```

I used `sqlacodegen` tool to autogenerate the appropriate SQLAlchemy model code, producing this output:

```python
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, LargeBinary, Unicode
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata


class DataType(Base):
    __tablename__ = "DataType"

    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = Column(Unicode(200), nullable=False, unique=True)


class DataSet(Base):
    __tablename__ = "DataSet"

    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    TypeId = Column(ForeignKey("DataType.Id"), nullable=False)

    DataType = relationship("DataType")


class ScalarData(DataSet):
    __tablename__ = "ScalarData"

    DataSetId = Column(ForeignKey("DataSet.Id"), primary_key=True)
    Value = Column(LargeBinary, nullable=False)
```

The problem occurs when trying to insert into `ScalarData` using the ORM `session.add()` style. It appears that, when adding a `ScalarData` object, SQLAlchemy *always* tries to create a new `DataSet` object to be referenced in `DataSetId` - but this fails, because the new `DataSet` object provides a null value for `DataTypeId`, which is non-nullable.

The desired behaviour is that I can create a `DataSet` explicitly, and then pass its `Id` as the value for `DataSetId` in creating a new `ScalarData` object - but when I do this, it seems that the passed-in value for `DataSetId` is completely ignored, and SQLAlchemy still tries to create a new `DataSet`.

Strangely, the problem does *not* seem to occur if I insert the new `ScalarData` using `session.execute()`.

The following is a minimal example to reproduce the error, starting from an empty database with the foregoing schema:

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

engine = create_engine(
    "mssql+pyodbc://username:password@localhost/my_database?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
)

session = Session(bind=engine)

datatype = DataType(Name="foo")
session.add(datatype)
session.flush()

dataset1 = DataSet(TypeId=datatype.Id)
session.add(dataset1)
session.flush()

dataset2 = DataSet(TypeId=type.Id)
session.add(dataset2)
session.flush()

session.execute(
    ScalarData.__table__.insert().values(DataSetId=dataset1.Id, Value=b"123")
)
session.flush() # this goes through just fine

data = ScalarData(DataSetId=dataset2.Id, Value=b"123")
session.add(data)
session.flush() # error raised here
```

The exception raised is the following:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DataTypeId', table 'my_database.dbo.DataSet'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (515) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: INSERT INTO [DataSet] ([DataTypeId]) OUTPUT inserted.[Id] VALUES (?)]
[parameters: (None,)]
```

I tried disabling the `NOT NULL` constraint on `DataTypeId`, just to see what happens when the query succeeds in whatever it's trying to do. In that case, the SQL produced is as follows:

```sql
INSERT INTO [DataSet] ([DataTypeId]) OUTPUT inserted.[Id] VALUES (?)
(None,)
INSERT INTO [ScalarData] ([DataSetId], [Value]) VALUES (?, ?)
(27, bytearray(b'123'))
```

The value 27 above is indeed the `Id` value of the newly-created `DataSet` row (this varies with each call, of course). This happens regardless of the value of `DataSetId` passed in to `ScalarData`.

I tried adding `autoincrement=False` to the `DataSetId = Column(...)` call in the `ScalarData` model definition, but the behaviour is completely unchanged.

I'm pretty much stumped at this point. Any insight into how to solve this problem, or even just why it is happening, would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but why does ScalarData inherit from DataSet? If that's directly from sqlacodegen, I think that's a bug.